# Converting a number to binary with a fixed length

Tags: python, for-loop

Say I get a random number between 1 and 127. I change the number to binary and remove the `0b` from it with the following code:

```
key_one= int(raw_input("Enter key (0 <= key <= 127): "))

if key_one in range(128):
    bin_key_one=bin(key_one)[2:]
print bin_key_one
else:
    print "You have to enter key (0 <= key <= 127)"
```

Now I want to make it 7-characters long by padding the beginning with zeros as necessary. I think I need to use a for loop, but can someone show me how to do it?

Comment: `if key_one in range(128)` could simply be replaced by `if 0 <= key_one <= 127` (which is more general, because it easily accommodates numbers much larger than 127).

Answer (score 97, accepted):

No you don't.

```
>>> '{0:07b}'.format(12)
'0001100'
```

Comment: +1: this avoids the conversion to binary, which might change in the future.

Comment: I'm a little stunned -- I've been using Python for a couple of years and have never seen str.format() before. I've always used C-style formatted print in Python, which, as it happens, doesn't support binary.

Comment: Now it's `f'{12:07b}'`

Comment: How can the 7 be replaced with some variable `length`?

Comment: f'{num:0{num_bits}b}'. Edit: added as answer to this question

Answer (score 39):

So it happens that Python has a string method `.zfill()` for that:

```
>>> '1'.zfill(7)
'0000001'
>>> '10010'.zfill(7)
'0010010'
```

Answer (score 6):

With Python 3.6's new [f-strings](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0498/), you can now do:

```py
key_one = int(input("Enter key (0 <= key <= 127): "))

if key_one in range(128):
    bin_key_one = f'{key_one:07b}'
    print(bin_key_one)
else:
    print("You have to enter key (0 <= key <= 127)")
```

Comment: Great solution. Zero prefix fill for this solution: `print(f'{key_one:b}'.zfill(20))` where `key_one` is the base10 number you'd like to print in binary and `20` the max zero prefix length.

Answer (score 4):

If you want variable length:

```py
>>> n = 12
>>> l = 7
>>> bin(n)[2:].zfill(l)
'0001100'
```

Answer (score 2):

You can use `str.rjust` too if you want to be flexible on the character to use as padding rather than just `0`:

```
>>> s = '111'
>>> s.rjust(8, '0')
'00000111'
>>> s.rjust(8, 'x')
'xxxxx111'
```

Answer (score 1):

Once for my project i needed to convert an integer to binary with variable length of binary string so i did

```
num_bits = 12
num = 4
f'{num:0{num_bits}b}'
```

Output
`000000000100`

Answer (score 1):

In 2022 python 3.8, f strings can accomplish this with this code.

```
f'{your_number:07b}'
```

If you wanted to convert strings to fixed binary you could do this

```
to_bin = [f'{ord(i):07b}' for i in input_data]
```

You can also use any number equal or greater than 7. Say you wanted 24bit. The length should always be preceded by 0.

```
f'{9:024b}'
```

Output: 000000000000000000001001

Answer (score 1):

Converting decimal to binary with desired significant digits and vice -versa

```
# Function returns decimal representation
def bin_float(binStr, places = 10):
    if binStr.find('.') >= 0:
        whole, dec = binStr.split(".")
    else:
        whole, dec = str(int(binStr)), '0'        
    x = 0
    N = len(whole)-1
    for k in range(N+1):
        x += int(whole[N-k])*2**k
    N = len(dec)
    for k in range(N):
        dx = int(dec[k])/2**(k+1)
        x += dx
    return(x)
 
# Function returns binary representation
def float_bin(x, places = 5):    
    # Convert an integer number to it's
    # respective binary representation
    if int(x) == x:
        return('{:b}'.format(int(x)))

    # Separate x to integer and decimal parts
    # and store in two separate variables
    whole = int(x)
    dec = abs(x - whole)
 
    # Convert the whole number part to it's
    # respective binary representation
    binStr = '{:b}'.format(whole)+'.'

    # Check if |x| > 0 for needed significant digits
    Sw = whole != 0
    
    # Iterate for significant/decimal digits
    Dig = 0
    while (Dig < places):     
        # Multiply the decimal value by 2
        # and separate the whole number part
        # and decimal part
        dec *= 2
        whole = int(dec)
        dec = abs(dec - whole)

        # Keep adding the integer parts
        # receive to the result variable
        binStr += str(whole)

        # Stating significant digit from non zero value
        if Sw:
            Dig += 1
        else:
            Sw = whole != 0

    # if last digit is 1, need roundoff truncation
    if binStr[-1] == '1':
        k = len(binStr)-1
        while (k > 0) and (binStr[k] in ['.', '1']):
            if binStr[k] == '1':
                binStr = binStr[:k]+'0'+binStr[k+1:]
            k -= 1
            
        if len(binStr)-1-k > places:
            binStr = binStr[:k]+'1'+binStr[k+1:-1]
        else:
            binStr = binStr[:k]+'1'+binStr[k+1:]
    return(binStr[:-1])
```

Test the code:

```
def do_for(x, p):
    bx = float_bin(x, places = p)
    Dx = bin_float(bx)
    rel = 100*abs(1-Dx/x)
    if rel >= 1:
        print('\n value = {:.6e} binary = {} ({} sig. digits)'.format(x, bx, p), \
              '\n saved = {:.6e}  Error = {:.2f}\%'.format(Dx, rel))
    else:
        print('\n value = {:.6e} binary = {} ({} sig. digits)'.format(x, bx, p), \
              '\n saved = {:.6e}  Error = {:.1e}\%'.format(Dx, rel))

do_for(0.234, 8)
do_for(0.234, 3)
do_for(0.234, 2)
do_for(15/16, 4)
do_for(31/32, 4)
do_for(1.00052123, 12)
do_for(0.00052123, 8)
```

results:

```
 value = 2.340000e-01 binary = 0.0011110000 (8 sig. digits) 
 saved = 2.343750e-01  Error = 1.6e-01\%

 value = 2.340000e-01 binary = 0.00111 (3 sig. digits) 
 saved = 2.187500e-01  Error = 6.52\%

 value = 2.340000e-01 binary = 0.010 (2 sig. digits) 
 saved = 2.500000e-01  Error = 6.84\%

 value = 9.375000e-01 binary = 0.1111 (4 sig. digits) 
 saved = 9.375000e-01  Error = 0.0e+00\%

 value = 9.687500e-01 binary = 1.000 (4 sig. digits) 
 saved = 1.000000e+00  Error = 3.23\%

 value = 1.000521e+00 binary = 1.00000000001 (12 sig. digits) 
 saved = 1.000488e+00  Error = 3.3e-03\%

 value = 5.212300e-04 binary = 0.000000000010001001 (8 sig. digits) 
 saved = 5.226135e-04  Error = 2.7e-01\%
```

Answer (score -2):

Try this:

```
for i in range(1, 127):
'0'*(7-len(bin(i)[2:]))+bin(i)[2:]
```

Comment: The built-in `zfill()` does exactly this…