# How to get all combination of n binary value?

Tags: python, list, math

In Python, how can I get all combinations of `n` binary values `0` and `1`?

For example, if `n = 3`, I want to have

```
[ [0,0,0], [0,0,1], [0,1,0], [0,1,1], ... [1,1,1] ]  #total 2^3 combinations
```

How can I do this?

Comment: @eumiro, I think my question is also equivalent to this one, http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3252528/converting-a-number-to-binary-with-a-fixed-length , but that answer gives a string instead of a list.

Answer (score 101, accepted):

Use [`itertools.product`](http://docs.python.org/2/library/itertools.html#itertools.product)

```
import itertools
lst = list(itertools.product([0, 1], repeat=3))
```

This will yield a list of tuples (see [here](http://ideone.com/rXZsIG))

You can easily change this to use a variable `repeat`:

```
n = 3
lst = list(itertools.product([0, 1], repeat=n))
```

If you need a list of lists, then you can use the `map` function (thanks @Aesthete).

```
lst = map(list, itertools.product([0, 1], repeat=n))
```

Or in Python 3:

```
lst = list(map(list, itertools.product([0, 1], repeat=n)))
# OR
lst = [list(i) for i in itertools.product([0, 1], repeat=n)]
```

Note that using `map` or a list comprehension means you don't need to convert the product into a list, as it will iterate through the `itertools.product` object and produce a list.

Comment: +1 - `map(list, product([0, 1], repeat=3))` will return the same format in case the OP is interested.

Comment: This is great, tuple is ok too.

Comment: @Volatility, just of curiosity, how do you know this? I had no clue how to find this function from the Python documentation.

Comment: @LWZ It [comes with experience](http://stackoverflow.com/a/2576240/1907098). (see point 6)

Comment: @Volatility, what a great post, thanks!

Comment: Thank you! This was extremely helpful

Comment: @Volatility thank you for the solution, I am trying to the same thing with 26 variables but I think my Jupyter NB runs out of memory. Do you know how I can possibly tackle this issue. Thanks.

Comment: @aditya lahiri the array size will be 2^n x n.  For 26 that's quite a long array.

Answer (score 17):

Without using any in-build functions or smart techniques we can get like this.

```
def per(n):
    for i in range(1<<n):
        s=bin(i)[2:]
        s='0'*(n-len(s))+s
        print (map(int,list(s)))
per(3)
```

output

```
[0, 0, 0]
[0, 0, 1]
[0, 1, 0]
[0, 1, 1]
[1, 0, 0]
[1, 0, 1]
[1, 1, 0]
[1, 1, 1]
```

Comment: For me, this yields:
<map object at 0x000001B30C760128>
<map object at 0x000001B30C760048>
<map object at 0x000001B30C760048>
<map object at 0x000001B30C760048>
<map object at 0x000001B30C760048>
<map object at 0x000001B30C760048>
<map object at 0x000001B30C760048>
<map object at 0x000001B30C760048>

Comment: Have to call (list(map...)) to get actual lists out

Comment: Great idea! here is a simple version with format function:
```
def per(n):
   for i in range(1<<n):
     s="{:03b}".format(i)
     print(list(map(int, list(s))))

>>> per(3)

Answer (score 4):

Following will give you all such combinations

```
bin = [0,1]
[ (x,y,z) for x in bin for y in bin for z in bin ]
```

Comment: He gives `n=3` as an example only, so he wants to have this parametrized.

Comment: This works but n can't be large...

Comment: This wont scale!