# How can I speed up this two-lines code?

Tags: python, performance, loops

I need to speed up the following code:

```
for i in range(0, 2**N):

    output[i] = f(np.array(map(int, bin(i)[2:].zfill(N))))
```

`N` is around `30`, so the code is very slow (it takes about 33 hours on my laptop). The argument of the function `f()` is the binary representation of the index `i`, and `f()` can be an arbitrary vectorizable function. I'm not an expert, but in order to speed up the code, I was thinking to get rid of the `for` loop, which means that I need to vectorize the argument of `f()`. In other words, I have to create a matrix with the binary representations of the numbers from `0` to `2**N`. This can be achieved through the following code:

```
list(itertools.product([0, 1], repeat=N))
```

that I have found at [this link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14931769/how-to-get-all-combination-of-n-binary-value). However, it seems to me that `itertools` is very slow, and clearly it takes a lot of memory since `2**30` is about one billion.

Do you have any suggestion for making this code faster? Thanks in advance.

Comment: You seem to be throwing away all but the last value of `output`.

Comment: Instead of producing a billion element array, why not rewrite as a generator?

Comment: Look up generators and the `yield` command.

Comment: @ user2357112: Hops, you're right. I've fixed it!

Comment: Possible also try the more python syntax `['do something' for i in ...]`

Comment: If `f` is computationally expensive there might not be much that you can do. If it takes e.g. a 10th of a millisecond for a single function evaluation, and you are doing over a billion such evaluations, you are looking at around 30 hours no matter what. Perhaps you could refactor so that the computation that `f` does is implemented directly in the loop. At least that would save the overhead of a billion function calls.

Comment: Also if you are using Python 2.7, by all means use "xrange" , not "range" - that  alone would create 2 ^30 objects in your system memory.

Comment: Are you actually using all billion values? Can you just generate each value as it is called and [then store that value if it is called again](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Memoization)?

Comment: I didn't know about generators, so I'm going to try also this option. Unfortunately I think memoization cannot be applied to my case, but thanks for the suggestion!

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Always profile:

```
>>> timeit.timeit("for i in range(0, 2**N): numpy.array(map(int, bin(i)[2:].zfill(N)))", "import numpy; N=5", number=100000)
26.472519159317017
>>> timeit.timeit("for t in itertools.product((0, 1), repeat=N): numpy.array(t)", "import numpy, itertools; N=5", number=100000)
6.129688024520874
```

You can see that the `itertools.product` method is considerably faster, since it doesn't has to fiddle around with strings.

The problem could be that most of the time is spent in the `f` function though.

Another solution could be to make `f` accept an integer, and use it as a binary field.

Comment: Additionally: Time for 2^24 `pass` operations on a recentish MBP: 883ms with just `range`, 501ms with `xrange`, 1.92s with a function call to `pass` and `range`, and 1.58s for function call + `xrange`.

Comment: Cool, I tried with `N=20` and it takes 1 min rather than 1.5 min. This will save a lot of time for larger `N`. I guess 22 hours vs 33 for `N=30`.