# create variable size array

Tags: python-3.x, numpy

I would like to create an numpy array like the one below, except I want to be able to create a variable shape array.  So for the one below it would be n=3.  Is there an a slick way to do this with numpy, or do I need a for loop.

output data:

```
import numpy as np

np.array([1,0,0],[0,1,0],[0,0,1],[1,1,1],[0,0,0])
```

Comment: you want to create array with random numbers using given shape?

Comment: Do you want to create a dynamic array?

Comment: You are making us guess - what size?  what pattern? just what do you mean by 'variable'?

Answer (score 0):

Say you want to create array with name `d` having `row` number of rows and `col` number of columns. 
It would also initialize all elements of the array with 0.

```
d = [[0 for x in range(col)] for y in range(row)]
```

You can access any element I,j by d[i][j].

Comment: The OP hasn't mentioned that there are `row` number of rows and `col` number of columns.

Comment: sorry I don't think I worded this very well but I also think I found the answer in another post https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14931769/how-to-get-all-combination-of-n-binary-value