# Change zeroes in 2D array one by one, and put the resulting arrays into another array in Python

Tags: python, arrays, loops, multidimensional-array, append

I am trying to achieve the following. I have a 2D array, which is of a 4x4 dimension. I want to get all possibilities, where I can insert a single 1 instead of a zero, and return an array, which contains all of these possibilities

So if we take:

```
[[0, 1, 0, 0], [0, 0, 1, 0], [0, 0, 0, 0], [0, 0, 0, 0]]
```

would result in:

```
[[1, 1, 0, 0], [0, 0, 1, 0], [0, 0, 0, 0], [0, 0, 0, 0]]
[[0, 1, 1, 0], [0, 0, 1, 0], [0, 0, 0, 0], [0, 0, 0, 0]]
[[0, 1, 0, 1], [0, 0, 1, 0], [0, 0, 0, 0], [0, 0, 0, 0]]
...
```

There would be a total of 14 entries in the resulting array, since there were 14 zeroes in the input array.

The problem is, that the code I have currently *should* work, as far as I understand, but I can't seem to get where it goes wrong.

```
def getPossibilities(arr):
    p = []
    for i in range(4):
        for j in range(4):
            if arr[i][j] == 0:
                p.append(arr)
                p[-1][i][j]=1  
    return p


for i in getPossibilities([[0,1,0,0],[0,0,1,0],[0,0,0,0],[0,0,0,0]]):
    print(i)
```

This results in 14 arrays of solid ones.

I included the way I check the results, in case there is an error there. I also tried with first copying the `arr` array into a temporary one, then make the changes, but to no avail.

What goes wrong here? I cannot seem to find an answer. Also, is there a more elegant and faster way of doing this? It would be really beneficial for my usecase.

Thank you very much in advance!

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to get all combination of n binary value?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14931769/how-to-get-all-combination-of-n-binary-value)

Answer (score 1):

This is somewhat tricky but since you have a list of lists, the copy won't work and you will be changing the array every time, what you need is deepcopy:

```
import copy

def getPossibilities(arr):
    p = []
    for i in range(4):
        for j in range(4):
            if arr[i][j] == 0:
                tmp = copy.deepcopy(arr)
                tmp[i][j]=1
                p.append(tmp)  
    return p

for i in getPossibilities([[0,1,0,0],[0,0,1,0],[0,0,0,0],[0,0,0,0]]):
    print(i)

[[1, 1, 0, 0], [0, 0, 1, 0], [0, 0, 0, 0], [0, 0, 0, 0]]
[[0, 1, 1, 0], [0, 0, 1, 0], [0, 0, 0, 0], [0, 0, 0, 0]]
[[0, 1, 0, 1], [0, 0, 1, 0], [0, 0, 0, 0], [0, 0, 0, 0]]
[[0, 1, 0, 0], [1, 0, 1, 0], [0, 0, 0, 0], [0, 0, 0, 0]]
[[0, 1, 0, 0], [0, 1, 1, 0], [0, 0, 0, 0], [0, 0, 0, 0]]
[[0, 1, 0, 0], [0, 0, 1, 1], [0, 0, 0, 0], [0, 0, 0, 0]]
[[0, 1, 0, 0], [0, 0, 1, 0], [1, 0, 0, 0], [0, 0, 0, 0]]
[[0, 1, 0, 0], [0, 0, 1, 0], [0, 1, 0, 0], [0, 0, 0, 0]]
[[0, 1, 0, 0], [0, 0, 1, 0], [0, 0, 1, 0], [0, 0, 0, 0]]
[[0, 1, 0, 0], [0, 0, 1, 0], [0, 0, 0, 1], [0, 0, 0, 0]]
[[0, 1, 0, 0], [0, 0, 1, 0], [0, 0, 0, 0], [1, 0, 0, 0]]
[[0, 1, 0, 0], [0, 0, 1, 0], [0, 0, 0, 0], [0, 1, 0, 0]]
[[0, 1, 0, 0], [0, 0, 1, 0], [0, 0, 0, 0], [0, 0, 1, 0]]
[[0, 1, 0, 0], [0, 0, 1, 0], [0, 0, 0, 0], [0, 0, 0, 1]]
```