# Converting a binary formatted string (with leading zeros) to an integer and back again

Tags: python, string, python-2.7, binary

I have converted 4 characters ATCG in to binary format i.e

```
00 replacing A 
11 replacing T 
10 replacing C 
01 replacing G
```

So a character string

```
AGAGAGAGTGATAGA
```

after conversion will look like

```
001000100010001011100011001000
```

Once I get this value I convert this binary in to its corresponding integer i.e

```
143177928.
```

The issue is, when I want to get back to binary again, it gives me

```
0b1000100010001011100011001000
```

which is not the correct representation of original character string because it omits all the zeros from far left after 1.

So I have written a method implementing binary conversion and I know how long the binary string should be. So in the end I just remove 0b from the returned binary and append 0s in the far left i.e

```
#zeros = length of original binary - length of returned binary (0b removed)
```

Is there any better way of doing this conversion??

I am coding this in python.

Comment: yes, the problem is with your encoding scheme... any number of leading zeros is the same binary number. you can only 'zero pad' the number to a fixed length in a string representation

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3252528/converting-a-number-to-binary-with-a-fixed-length

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can append a flag bit after the MSB to protect all the leading zeros.

**Step 1: Conversion**

Add a single "flag" bit at the end and convert your bit string.

```
In [6]: converted_str = '001000100010001011100011001000'

In [9]: num = int('1' + converted_str, 2)

In [10]: num
Out[10]: 1216919752
```

**Step 2: Re-conversion**

Use the `format` method to convert your number back to a bit string, while stripping off the first "flag" bit.

```
In [12]: reconverted_str = format(num, 'b')[1:]

In [13]: reconverted_str
Out[13]: '001000100010001011100011001000'
```

Comment: it works.. fewer steps than mine. Many thanks. lets see if we get any other ideas. :)

Answer (score 0):

Use `'{0:0{1}b}'.format(num, num_digits)`

This will add leading 0's until the number is `num_digits`. The 'b' specifies that `num` should be converted to binary.

Comment: this was in my original method from previous stack suggestions. but I think adding a single bit initially and stripping it in the end is more efficient. thanks for your suggestion anyways.

Comment: More efficient in what way?

Comment: that way I am not dependent on the length of string to figure out how many zeros I want. With above method I know I have to add and strip a single bit so I am kind of avoiding variables for length of string and leading zeros.